# jQuery swapping elements around

Tags: jquery, datatables

Datatables automatically generated the following "Showing 1 to 10 of 20 Tasks" and a pagination block with page numbers.

All I want to do is swap them around, so that the info appears on the right and the pagination appears on the left.

How can I do that with jQuery? I can't just edit the HTML because Datatable auto-generates this code:

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <div aria-live="polite" role="status" id="tasks-table_info" class="dataTables_info">Showing 1 to 10 of 20 tasks</div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-6">
    <div id="tasks-table_paginate" class="dataTables_paginate paging_simple_numbers">
        <ul class="pagination">
            <li id="tasks-table_previous" tabindex="0" aria-controls="tasks-table" class="paginate_button previous disabled"><a href="#">Previous</a></li>
            <li tabindex="0" aria-controls="tasks-table" class="paginate_button active"><a href="#">1</a></li>
            <li tabindex="0" aria-controls="tasks-table" class="paginate_button "><a href="#">2</a></li>
            <li id="tasks-table_next" tabindex="0" aria-controls="tasks-table" class="paginate_button next"><a href="#">Next</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any ideas are welcome, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't modify the plugin html, then try to execute the below query once the plugin is initialized. But it will be better if you can modify the plugin source to swap the element positions

```
var $p = $('#tasks-table_info').parent();
$p.next().insertBefore($p)
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [DOM positioning](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/dom.html)

It should be possible to define the positions of all additional information around the table.

I tried it in JS Fiddle. I needed some additional CSS:

```
.dataTables_info {
clear: none !important;
    float:right !important;
}

.dataTables_paginate {
  float: left !important;
  text-align: justify !important;
  padding-top: 0 !important;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').dataTable( {
    "dom": '<"top">rt<"bottom"pi><"clear">'
  });
});
```

JSFiddle: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/2524hs35/)

Comment: Someone else replied here - but it looks like they deleted their message. Either way, their idea of  `var $p = $('#tasks-table_info').parent(); $p.next().insertBefore($p);` worked beautifully. If they put it back I'll mark it as the answer. But Michael Filler, as yours is the only comment left, you get the vote. :)

Comment: @b85411 I have undeleted my answer, but if there is a built in support from the plugin then it is better to use that

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#historyTab').dataTable({
    "pageLength": 3,
    "dom":'<"top">t<"bottom">ip<"clear">' //https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/dom.html
  });
});
```

```css
#historyTab_paginate{float:left;}
#historyTab_info{float:right;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

 <table id="historyTab" class="tbAD table table-striped table-bordered no-footer dataTable" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead style="display:none">
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot style="display:none">
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>2011/07/25</td>
                <td>$170,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>2009/01/12</td>
                <td>$86,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
                <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>2012/03/29</td>
                <td>$433,060</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Airi Satou</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>33</td>
                <td>2008/11/28</td>
                <td>$162,700</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2012/12/02</td>
                <td>$372,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
                <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>59</td>
                <td>2012/08/06</td>
                <td>$137,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>55</td>
                <td>2010/10/14</td>
                <td>$327,900</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```